# How can I simplify addressing an iOS device using Bonjour?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http, networking, bonjour

I would like to make an application for iOS devices that would communicate with a special type of remote device using HTTP POST requests. The problem is that this device would actually act in the role of a client, while iOS device has to be the server accepting the requests. The next problem, host name and port has to be configured statically at the device sending the requests.

While I'm aware it's possible to give it a try using Dynamic DNS services and UPnP/IGD or NAT-PMP to overcome the problem with iOS device being behind the NAT router, I was wondering whether using Bonjour could simplify the problem in some way. I'm quite a newbie in networking so I'm looking for the direction and want to avoid research of Bonjour if it's not going to bring me anything.

Any other idea of how to solve the problem is appreciated as well.

Comment: A better description of the network topology might help- are the iOS device and other 'client' device on the same local network?

Comment: that's actually the point, they're not, so they need to communicate over the internet, while iOS might use wifi or 3G being behind some router and NAT

Comment: Although Bonjour (mDNS) can be used on a WAN, it's really designed for advertising / discovery on link-local networks. uPNP can't really be relied upon on iOS if the iPhone is connected through the cellular network. Would the device be internet-facing or behind a router too?

Comment: I think it's more realistic to expect it would possibly be behind a router as well

Comment: Some kind of server acting as a go-between would be the typical solution, but I assume you want the devices to discover each other without a 3rd party?

Comment: Exactly, I'm exploring the possibilities, having a server in between would surely simplify it, the question is if it's possible to do it without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a think about this. IMHO you can't guarantee you'll always be able to expose an iOS based service over a WAN (although it's possible) so this isn't practical.

The best solution I suggest is using uPNP to open the device behind a router to the outside world, then have it send an [iOS push notification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html) to the iPhone with the details (hostname, ip, port, etc).

The iPhone would then would then have to set up some kind of persistent connection with the firewalled device to receive data.

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour is a good system to discover and connect to services/clients, but only on your local network. I don't think it is a good idea to try it over the internet.